# Multiplying two inputs with JavaScript & displaying in text box

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript & am looking for some help doing simple multiplication of two numbers & displaying the result in another text box. I have been trying to get this working for days to no avail :(

Here is the basic HTML along with the JavaScript & a link to a fiddle here http://jsbin.com/egeKAXif/1/edit

What am I doing wrong?

The application I want to write will have at least 12 rows, how would I extend the JavaScript / HTML to accommodate this? Would each input identifier need to be unique?

Any help appreciated :)

```
    <table width="80%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Box 1</th>
        <th>Box 2</th>
        <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="box1" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="box2" type="text" onchange="calculate()" /></td>
        <td><input id="result" /></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

<script>

    function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = box1 * box2;
    result.innerHTML = myResult;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first thing you have got to change is the line with the multiplication. It should be: `var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;`

You should not use innerHTML with input fields -  use value.

Additional to that, the `onchange` event fires only when the input looses the focus. You might want to use the `oninput` event.

Take a look at the working example: http://jsbin.com/OJOlARe/1/edit

Comment: Genius! It's working now :)

How would I extend this to work on a table with 12 rows? I'm thinking I need to iterate over the entire table? Do I need different IDs for each input / result ??

Comment: Hey @user3213157! If you find this answer useful, you can make it the "accepted answer" by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer. As for the new question you ask in the previous comment: better to ask a whole new question for that if it's still a problem! And: welcome to StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Here is an example for multiple fields: http://jsbin.com/uNOVeHig/1/edit Hope you don't mind me using jquery. But it makes it a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

```
<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Box 1</th>
    <th>Box 2</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate();" /></td>
    <td><input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate();" /></td>
    <td><input id="result" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>


    function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
          document.getElementById('result').value = myResult;

    }
</script>
```

You cannot use `result.innerHTML = myResult;` on javascript variable directly. First you need to read the html dom element `document.getElementById('result')` then call the value property for input fields or innerHTML for div, span elements.

Comment: It would be great if you would add a few comments to explain this answer. Code-only answers frequently get deleted upon review. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).